# What's wrong with named pipes used between 2 processes (no. 2)?

Tags: bash, process, named-pipes

So, let's start from beginning: 2 processes 1 pipe to communicate, right? No! because communication is blocking, one waits for another. We need results from the second process through a different channel. Though it seems redundant it is not.

Let's change it a bit: 2 processes 2 pipes, you can call one process the server and the other the client. One pipe sends jobs to clients and the other is used to collect results from the clients to the server.

For convenience we call each pipe with the process name that is used for reading so, london reads london pipe and so on. That's the diagram of pipes and processes:

```
london ----writes madrid pipe-------->
london <----reads london pipe------  |
                                  ^  |
                                  |  |
madrid ----writes london pipe----->  v
madrid <----reads madrid pipe---------
```

Let's use 'london' as server and 'madrid' as client: server is responsible to end the endless loop.

And this is the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -u failglob
shopt -s extglob nullglob dotglob

DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )

function london (){
   local i message answer london madrid
   london=london_$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$$
   madrid=madrid_$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$$
   cd $DIR
   mkfifo $london
   mkfifo $madrid
   ( madrid $madrid $london ) &
   echo "parent id: $$, child id: $!"
   i=0
   #a mesterious situation: sometimes '3< $london' just breaks it (?!)
   exec 3<> $london
   exec 4> $madrid

   while true; do

      message="Greetings from London!($i)"
      echo "$message" >&4

      read -r answer <&3
      echo 'London says:> '"$answer" #>& /dev/stdout
      (( i++ ))

      if [[ i -gt 1 ]]; then
         echo 'quit' >&4
         break
      fi
   done

   wait
   cd "$DIR"
   rm -rf $london
   rm -rf $madrid
}

function madrid (){
   local i message answer madrid london
   madrid=$1
   london=$2
   cd $DIR
   i=0
   exec 3> $london
   exec 4< $madrid
   while true; do

      read -r answer <&4
      echo 'Madrid says:> '"$answer" #>& /dev/stdout

      message="Greetings from Madrid!($i)"
      echo "$message" >&3
      (( i++ ))

      if [[ $answer = 'quit' ]]; then
         break
      fi
   done
}

london
```

At function 'london' there is a comment just before

```
   exec 3<> $london
```

if you change this to

```
   exec 3< $london
```

as it should(!) be then, I faced a situation where my program stalled repeatedly!
After a few changes from <> to < and vice versa the problem eliminated and I can't reproduce it! I'm using an Ubuntu system so if anybody can test the program with his/her system and post some comments it will welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Here the program only stopped if it was started in the background, due to tty output. You should have attached `strace` to the first process when you could reproduce the problem.